# Statistics: Maximum Likelihood and Method of Moments

Tags: parameters, statistics, mle

I am trying to find the maximum likelihood estimators and the method of moments of the following:

```
g(x;w;s) = pdf =  1/we^((-x-s)/(w)), for x > s
```

For finding the MEE of s and w, I know I have to solve the following two functions:

```
(1) xbar = mu 
(2) 1/n summation Xi^2 = mu^2 + var
```

I found the E[x] = mu = integral from s to infinity x*1/we^((-x-s)/w)dx =

```
e^(-2s/w)(w+s)
```

I then found E[X^2] = var = integral from s to infinity x^2*1/we^((-x-s)/w)dx =

```
e^(-2s/w)(2w^2+2ws+s^2)
```

From here I now have my two equations:

```
(1) xbar = e^(-2s/w)(w+s)
(2) 1/n summation Xi^2 = mu^2 + e^(-2s/w)(2w^2+2ws+s^2)
```

Now I know I need to solve the two systems of equations, but I am having a difficult time solving them. I wanted to solve the first equation for either w or s, and they substitute into the second equation, but I cannot figure it out. I am wondering if I integrated on the correct bounds? It made sense to me, but it might be wrong. So since I couldn't get any further using the MME, I attempted the method of maximum likelihood and I got the following:

```
P(X1=x1, X2=x2,...,Xn=xn)
= P(X1=x1)P(X2=x2)...P(Xn=xn)
= g(x1;w;s)g(x2;w;s)...g(xn;w,s)
= 1/we^((-x1-s)/w) * 1/we^((-x2-s)/w) *... * 1/we^((-xn-s)/w)
= 1/w^ne^(-1/w summation xi+s)
```

From here I am again stuck and I'm unsure if I even did this correctly. I don't know if what I did makes sense to anyone, but any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thank everyone!
Lizzie

p.s. I'm sorry it's hard to read my math problem in this format I typed it, I'm unfamiliar with this website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your integrals. `E[x] = mu != x*1/we^((-x-s)/w)dx` but rather is equal to  `x*1/we^((-(x-s)/w)dx = s + w`. I guess all your other errors follow because of the mistake in carrying forward the sign: `-(x-s) = -x + s`.

By the way, this density function corresponds to the **shifted exponential distribution**. Because if you take **X** to be exponentially distributed with mean **w** then **X-s** has density given by **g**.

Comment: what bounds are you integrating on? When I integrate x*1/we^((-(x-s)/w)dx from s<x<infinity, I am getting -(x-s)/w.

Comment: Well obviously from s to infinity. A simple change of variable `y = x - s` will give you the result I've mentioned.